# android style with no background image and no title bar

Tags: android, android-theme

I am adding this style to my app:

```
<style name="Theme.NoBackground.noTitleBar" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

because I need to hide the title bar and at the same time need to get rid of the background because I have a background image and don't need anything else to be placed under it.

Would that work because I am not able to see if the background is gone or not...

Comment: of course it will, you add this `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`, right?

Comment: yes, I've written it as it is written in the code; but how can I know that the background image is gone?

Comment: if you don't add another background color, then the pixel in the screen will slighly mess up (black background), so suggestion is you add background color and not only @null